# Как сделать redirect из шаблона?

Tags: python, django

Сначала делается проверка авторизирован ли пользователь. Если да, то показываем ему форму, иначе нужно перенаправить на страницу авторизации. Можно ли это сделать как-то из шаблона?

```
form.html

<div class="container">
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
       
        <form action="{% url 'adding' 'string'%}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% else %}
        ?????????
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: {% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
{% endif %}

Answer (score 0):

Можно убрать `if` из шаблона и делать проверку на авторизацию в вьюхе, как описано в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required).

```py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_view(request):
    # Здесь Ваш код, который отправляет на form.html
    ...
```

Если юзер авторизован, вьюха даст ему `form.html`. Иначе отправит его на страницу авторизации.